# Background BLE triggers using Radius Networks Pro iBeacon SDK

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am developing with the Pro version of the Radius Networks iBeacon SDK on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running Android 4.3. The app has been successfully using the non-pro version 0.7 for a month now but I want the background events so I've gone to Pro version 1.0. The AndroidProximityLibrary project is a project dependency in Eclipse, and the `ProximityKit.properties` file is in `src/`.

The following code is my Application subclass, as described in the [documentation](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/background_launching.html). The app has BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions. Notice from the LogCat output that the `didDetermineStateForRegion()` method is not called after going to sleep as expected. What has to change to get something to happen in the background?

I have seen a similar question called [iBeacon background scanning PRO feature of RadiusNetworks library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21190719/823470) but the problem there seemed to be calling `IBeaconManager.unbind()` which caused the OS to clean up the service. My code never calls `IBeaconManager.unbind()`, only `IBeaconManager.bind()`.

```
public class ExampleApp extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier, IBeaconConsumer {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ExampleApp.class.getName();
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private IBeaconManager iBeacon;
    private Region region;

    public ExampleApp() {
        String uuid = "EBEFD083-70A2-47C8-9837-E7B5634DF520";
        region = new Region("com.example.ble", uuid, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        iBeacon = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        iBeacon.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000);
        iBeacon.setBackgroundScanPeriod(3000);
        iBeacon.bind(this);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG + ".onIBeaconServiceConnect", "connected to iBeacon service");
        try {
            iBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            String msg = "caught exception while enabling beacon ranging";
            Log.e(LOG_TAG + ".onIBeaconServiceConnect", msg, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG + ".didEnterRegion", "YEAH ENTERED");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG + ".didDetermineStateForRegion", "YEAH STATE");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG + ".didExitRegion", "YEAH EXITED");
    }

}
```

I ran the app outside beacon range, then walked into range. After 30 seconds nothing had happened so I pressed the Power button and still nothing happened. I plugged the phone in and got the trace from ADB.

#### LogCat at INFO level between sleep (Home then Power) and wake after 30 seconds (Power)

```
05-28 14:05:23.456: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [ps] Screen__Off(0) :  goToSleepFromNative:  (uid: 1000 pid: 2392)
05-28 14:05:23.456: I/PowerManagerService(2392): Going to sleep by user request...
05-28 14:05:23.471: W/KeyguardViewMediator(2392): wakeUpIfNeeded() mMaybeShow=true mRequestedWakeUp=false mShowing=false
05-28 14:05:23.516: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input11/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:23.516: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:23.516: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input10/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] autosuspend_earlysuspend_enable : 40
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] wait_for_fb_sleep : 40 (1, 0) -
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] autosuspend_earlysuspend_enable done : 40
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] wait_for_fb_wake : 40 (0, 0) +
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL] Off : 0s ago
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL]   PowerManagerService.WakeLocks: ref count=1
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL]   PowerManagerService.Broadcasts: ref count=1
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL]     mWakeLockSummary : 0x1
05-28 14:05:23.521: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL]       PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK              'ActivityManager-Sleep' (uid=1000, pid=2392, ws=null) (elapsedTime=42)
05-28 14:05:23.526: I/CAE(2392): onReceive(CaPowerManager.java:142) - AP_SLEEP
05-28 14:05:23.531: I/CAE(2392): sendCmdToSensorHub(SensorHubCommManager.java:146) - -76, 13, -46, 0, 
05-28 14:05:23.561: I/CAE(2392): parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:136) - buffer size = 3
05-28 14:05:23.561: I/CAE(2392): parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:147) - 2, 1, -46, 
05-28 14:05:23.591: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1989): setParameters(screen_state=off)
05-28 14:05:23.591: I/audio_wfd_hw(1989): adev_set_parameters() screen_state=off
05-28 14:05:23.616: I/NfcService(2909): # NativeNfcBrcmPowerMode; setPowerMode(android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF)
05-28 14:05:23.621: E/NfcService(2909): callback == null
05-28 14:05:23.691: I/AutoBackupUtil(9627): checkAutoBackupCondition returns : false
05-28 14:05:23.691: I/AutoBackupUtil(9627): bChargerConnected : true
05-28 14:05:23.691: I/AutoBackupUtil(9627): bWifiConnected : false
05-28 14:05:23.691: I/AutoBackupUtil(9627): bScreenOn : false
05-28 14:05:24.871: I/SurfaceFlinger(1986): id=996 Removed Uoast (5/6)
05-28 14:05:24.871: I/SurfaceFlinger(1986): id=996 Removed Uoast (-2/6)
05-28 14:05:28.526: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL] Off : 5s ago
05-28 14:05:38.541: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL] Off : 15s ago
05-28 14:05:51.251: E/Watchdog(2392): !@Sync 8274
05-28 14:05:53.556: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [PWL] Off : 30s ago
05-28 14:05:55.986: E/BatteryService(2392): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
05-28 14:05:56.081: E/Sensors(2392): Light old sensor_state 0, new sensor_state : 64 en : 1
05-28 14:05:56.096: I/SensorService(2392): info.selectDelay() ns=200000000  
05-28 14:05:56.101: I/PowerManagerService(2392): [ps] Screen__On(wake lock) :  wl: charger plug
05-28 14:05:56.101: I/PowerManagerService(2392): Waking up from sleep...
05-28 14:05:56.126: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] autosuspend_earlysuspend_disable : 41
05-28 14:05:56.151: I/KeyguardBackgroundView(2392): *** KeyguardEffectView getInstance ***
05-28 14:05:56.151: I/WindowManager(2392): No lock screen!
05-28 14:05:56.196: I/NfcService(2909): # NativeNfcBrcmPowerMode; setPowerMode(android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT)
05-28 14:05:56.266: E/videowall-TranscodeReceiver(10819): broadcastMSG : android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
05-28 14:05:56.276: I/EntropyMixer(2392): Writing entropy...
05-28 14:05:56.281: E/Sensors(2392): Light old sensor_state 64, new sensor_state : 0 en : 0
05-28 14:05:56.326: I/CAE(2392): onReceive(CaPowerManager.java:150) - POWER_CONNECTED
05-28 14:05:56.326: I/CAE(2392): sendCmdToSensorHub(SensorHubCommManager.java:146) - -76, 13, -42, 0, 
05-28 14:05:56.426: E/Launcher(2928): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
05-28 14:05:56.536: I/SSRMv2:Monitor(2392): fileWriteInt : /sys/class/power_supply/battery/siop_level  value : 100
05-28 14:05:56.546: E/Sensors(2392): Light old sensor_state 0, new sensor_state : 64 en : 1
05-28 14:05:56.556: I/SensorService(2392): info.selectDelay() ns=200000000  
05-28 14:05:56.556: E/Sensors(2392): Light old sensor_state 64, new sensor_state : 0 en : 0
05-28 14:05:56.556: E/MotionRecognitionService(2392):   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_USER_PRESENT  :: UNLOCK SCREEN
05-28 14:05:56.571: E/BatteryService(2392): Could not open /efs/FactoryApp/batt_cable_count
05-28 14:05:56.576: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] wait_for_fb_wake : 41 (1, 0) -
05-28 14:05:56.576: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] wait_for_fb_sleep : 41 (0, 0) +
05-28 14:05:56.576: I/libsuspend(2392): !@[s] autosuspend_earlysuspend_disable done : 41
05-28 14:05:56.576: E/SecTVOutService(1986): virtual void android::SecTVOutService::setHdmiStatus(uint32_t)::mSecHdmi.connect() fail
05-28 14:05:56.576: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input11/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:56.576: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:56.576: E/SEC PowerHAL(2392): sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input10/enabled: No such file or directory
05-28 14:05:56.616: I/CAE(2392): onReceive(CaPowerManager.java:146) - AP_WAKEUP
05-28 14:05:56.616: I/CAE(2392): sendCmdToSensorHub(SensorHubCommManager.java:146) - -76, 13, -47, 0, 
05-28 14:05:56.681: I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA(1989): setParameters(screen_state=on)
05-28 14:05:56.681: I/audio_wfd_hw(1989): adev_set_parameters() screen_state=on
05-28 14:05:56.796: E/SELinux(11287): Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file 
05-28 14:05:56.796: E/SELinux(11287):  
05-28 14:05:56.801: E/SELinux(11287): Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-N7105_4.3_0021
05-28 14:05:56.801: E/SELinux(11287):  
05-28 14:05:56.801: E/SELinux(11287):  
05-28 14:05:56.801: E/SELinux(11287): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
05-28 14:05:56.821: I/NfcService(2909): NFC: When Screen On, S View Cover also Open!!
05-28 14:05:56.821: I/NfcService(2909): # NativeNfcBrcmPowerMode; setPowerMode(android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON)
05-28 14:05:56.841: I/CAE(2392): parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:136) - buffer size = 3
05-28 14:05:56.841: I/CAE(2392): parse(SensorHubParserProvider.java:147) - 2, 1, -47, 
05-28 14:05:56.871: I/ActivityManager(2392): Killing proc 11287:com.sec.android.SimpleWidget/u0a10145: force stop com.sec.android.SimpleWidget
05-28 14:05:56.886: W/ActivityManager(2392): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10029
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call [`IBeaconManager.updateScanPeriods()`](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/javadocs/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/IBeaconManager.html#updateScanPeriods%28%29) after `setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod()` or `setBackgroundScanPeriod()` is called. Since my code didn't do that, the Radius SDK was still scanning at default intervals (10 minutes in the background).

Answer (score 1):

When using `RegionBootstrap`, you do not need to call `iBeacon.bind(this);` nor do you need an implementation for `onIBeaconServiceConnect()`.  This is because these tasks are handled internally by the `RegionBootstrap` class.

To fix this, try taking out your manual call to `iBeacon.bind(this);`

Comment: I removed `iBeacon.bind(this)` and started sporadically seeing callbacks happen. When I removed `onIBeaconServiceConnect()`, though, everything stopped until I readded it. What are the conditions that cause `didDetermineStateForRegion()` and `didEnterRegion()` to be called from a "background" state? In my testing I only have a success rate of about 10%.

Comment: The methods only get called when a beacon disappears or reappears from view.  Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: I noticed that you have code that starts ranging in onIBeaconServiceConnect(), but I do not see anyplace that you set up a RangeNotifier.  Is there code that does this that is not shown?  Are you expecting ranging functionality instead of the  monitoring functionality provided by the RegionBootstrap?

Comment: Yes, I always ran the app outside beacon range or with the beacon off, then walked into range or turned the beacon on. This is all the relevant code - the reason I had implemented `IBeaconConsumer` is because without it nothing got logged from `didEnterRegion()` and `didExitRegion()`.

Comment: I should clarify that at the moment, to get this stuff working, I'm not using any ranging. Once things look good then yes I need to merge this back into an existing app that does require ranging.